# Low speed of EF in first Query

Tags: performance, entity-framework, view

I'm using EF Code first, with one model that has over than 200 Entities(winforms), when i ran my program for first time, it took long time to run first query,then I used pre-generated views for improving performance, startup time reduced to about 12-13 seconds(before pregenerated views, startup time was about 30 seconds), which options i have, to reduce the time of my first query?

Comment: Are you sure all of this time is consumed by EF not the rest of your application, and what does that first query look like. I wouldnt expect that EF would take quite that long unless your entity graph has something crazy in it or you are recreating/seeding the DB or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have many options. First of all try to use the latest EF version - that means EF6 alpha 2 because there were some improvements but it may not be enough. IMHO add splash screen to your app and make the "first query" during application startup. WinForms application simply can have longer startup time if they perform some complex logic. Commonly whole application is initialized during startup so that it run smoothly once it is started.